# Deny all except a range of IP'S IIS 7.5 problem

Tags: iis-7.5, local-area-network, deny

I want to set up a Deny all rule for a specific range of IPS, so I wrote the range, lets say 76.200.0.0 and its mask 255.255.0.0.

The problem is that as my personal server is on a LAN, IIS takes the local IP of my router to look for an exception, so I have to add its local IP to a new rule exception, wich makes the "Deny all order" with no effect.

How can I set up this configuration within a LAN ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your routing/networking equipment is obscuring the actual remote IP from your IIS, then the filtering needs to occur on the a device where the remote IP is still unaltered.